# Get TYPO3 Extbase mm relation count

Tags: php, mysql, typo3, extbase

We created a simple mm relation between to models like so:

```
<?php
namespace VENDOR\COMPANY\Domain\Model;

class Posts extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity
{

//..

 /**
   * users
   *
   * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\VENDOR\COMPANY\Domain\Model\Users>
   */
   protected $likedBy = null;

 //..

}
```

The MySQL database creates a new mm table and also creates a counter column `users` in the `..domain_post` table. Is there a "lighter" way to get this counting than call all related users and count them?

```
$amountLikes = $post->getLikedBy()->count();
```

Imagine a list of posts with ~ 30000 likes each. The script starts to build up 30000 objects in the memory. Asking the posts table for the number sounds more realistic to me. But how to?

Answer (score 2):

Extbase Repositories got countAll() / countByProperty() by default. You can also add your own functions to the repository for just returning the object count of any query.

You may try something like this in your controller:

```
$amountLikes = $this->usersRepository->countByLikedPosts($anyPost);
```

This requires that your Users-model got something like a backreference property (like "likedPosts") to all posts that has been liked by a user.

Edit:
The likedPosts-property of users must be an Objectstorage, too. Because of this, the default countByXy function maybe does not work because Objectstorages requires contains()-constraints in a repository. So you may have to add your own function to the usersRespository - something like this:

```
public function countByLikedPost($post) {
    $query = $this->createQuery();
    return $query->matching($query->contains('likedPosts',$post))->count();
}
```

Comment: If you count the executed statement, extbase will still construct an extbase object for every matching entity. However it doesn't when you just call count without executing the query first, as stated in the docs   https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/6-Persistence/3-implement-individual-database-queries.html .

Comment: @j4k3 Thanks for this important suggestion j4k3 - I edited the answer above.

Answer (score 1):

If your concern here is the performance, you may want to consider redefining your relationship model. TYPO3 keeps relation fields for MM-relations in entities that automatically maintain the amount of related entities. You can then write a custom query that resolves the actual column content, which will be the amount of likes. Heres a blog post as a good starting point on how to do that.

http://lbrmedia.net/codebase/Eintrag/extbase-bidirektionale-mm-relation/

You also need to understand lazy loading relations, as, judging by your current model, the relation to users isn't lazy, which means that Extbase will instanciate all these users for every Post you load.

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/5-Domain/2-implementing-the-domain-model.html